# How to add html to returned json object via php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I was wondering how to add a html link to each JSON item as it is returned.

php file

```
//relevant code, $result contains sql query with records from a search
    $records = array();
    while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
        $records[] = $array;
     }
   echo(json_encode($records));
```

Output html via ajax

```
function responseReceived(e){
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
    }
```

Response is a `div` tag. So I was wondering how would I add `html` link (to another page) to each item within the `json`. Because at the moment it outputs `json` but it's not allowing me to add `html`. 
This is the current output, which is as expected due to me entering data via a form, I just want to add a small `html` link next to him.

```
[{"0":"1115","ID":"1115","1":"john","name":"john","2":"male","type":"male","3":"berk","country":"berk","4":"aus","region":"aus","5":"32.43","lon":"32.43","6":"32.54","lat":"32.54","7":"nothing to say","description":"nothing to say"}]
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: by loop ? can i see how is your json looks like ?

Comment: Just added how my json looks via the search form. I honestly don't know why but when I try to add it via loop it stops working. So I must be doing something stupidly wrong.

Comment: you are not using result returned by `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: What do you mean? Could you show e.g.? And I still wouldn't know how to add the html :/

Comment: I am using the result returned my the mysqli_fetch_array, code isn't working doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where will you get the link from?

Is the returned data the link or is the returned data some text that should be formatted as a link?

If it's the second one, you need to get the link from somewhere.

What you could do is storing some sort of link/id in the database and print that out in the json so it will output something like:

```
[{"url": "http://example.com", "content": "This is a link!"}]
```

I presume that you know how to do a ajax call, so let's just continue to the formatting:

```
// Let's make a function
function createLinks(json){

    // Let's parse the JSON first (if it's a string)
    json = JSON.parse(json);

    // Loop through all the elements
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){

        // Check if the fields exist
        if(json[i].url && json[i].content){

            // Creating a tag
            var a = document.createElement("a");

            // Let's add the values to the a tag
            a.href = json[i].url;
            a.textContent = json[i].content;
            // ^ or innerHTML if you want to have HTML code there

            // Appending to body element (just for this example)
            document.body.appendChild(a);

        }

    }

}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This simple code adds a link to every single array item. If you want to transform it to HTML, just create the HTML string and then you can insert it with innerHTML.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"0":"1115","ID":"1115","1":"john","name":"john","2":"male","type":"male","3":"berk","country":"berk","4":"aus","region":"aus","5":"32.43","lon":"32.43","6":"32.54","lat":"32.54","7":"nothing to say","description":"nothing to say"},{"0":"1115","ID":"1115","1":"john","name":"john","2":"male","type":"male","3":"berk","country":"berk","4":"aus","region":"aus","5":"32.43","lon":"32.43","6":"32.54","lat":"32.54","7":"nothing to say","description":"ggg"}]');
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    obj[i].link = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>';
}
```